# How to end my hangman game, and how to tell the user - Congrats

Tags: python

Okay so, three problems.

1- I'm using 'thing' and if statements to check the input of the user. So if his/her guessed word is complete it goes through as true in all the if statements and displays the final Congrats! But it's not working as it should.

2- Why isn't my elif statement working at the end? When the timer hits 0. That's zero guesses, so the game is over. But it's not working!

3- How can I keep track of the alphabets he/she uses up. The way it works now, if he/she guessed an alphabet on a 1st guess, on the 2nd guess that alphabet is not visible. But on the 3rd guess it'd come back. But what I want is to keep that alphabet invisible for the next coming guesses. Instead of it being the last guessed alphabet that disappears. I hope this is clear.

If anyone could just help out with 1 and 2 I would be super pleased! Namaste.

```
def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):

    a = string.ascii_lowercase
    for char1 in a:
        if char1 in letters_guessed:
           a = a.replace(char1,"")


    return(a)


def hangman(secret_word):
    timer = 6
    warning = 3
    secret_word = 'geranimo'
    alph = string.ascii_lowercase
    guessed_letters = len(secret_word) * ['_']


    if timer >= 1:
        while timer >= 1:
            print('You have', timer, 'guesses left.')
            letters_guessed = str(input('Guess a letter: '))


            if letters_guessed not in alph and warning >= 1:
                print('Only alphabets allowed!!!')
                print('You have',warning, 'warnings')
                warning -= 1

            if letters_guessed not in alph and warning <= 0:
                    timer -= 1

            for position, letter in enumerate(secret_word):
                if letter == letters_guessed:
                    guessed_letters[position] = letter
                    print(' '.join(guessed_letters))

            cons =['b','c','d','f','h','j','k','l','p','q','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']
            for thing in cons:
                if letters_guessed == thing: 
                    print('Wrong Consonant!')
                    timer -= 1
            vow =['u']
            for thing in vow:
                if letters_guessed == thing: 
                    print('Wrong Vowel!')
                    timer -= 2

            for thing in guessed_letters:
                if thing == 'g':
                    if thing == 'e':
                        if thing == 'r':
                            if thing == 'a':
                                if thing == 'n':
                                    if thing == 'i':
                                        if thing == 'm':
                                            if thing == 'o':
                                                print ('Congrats game won!')
                                                break
                else:
                    break



            alpha = get_available_letters(letters_guessed)
            for position, letter in enumerate(alpha):
                if letter == letters_guessed: 
                    alpha.delete(position)


            print('Available letters: ' + alpha)


    elif timer == 0:
        print("Game over douchebag")
        quit()
```

Comment: There are some large issues with your code. Not that it will not run, but it can be refactored to become much more Pythonic and clean. I would recommend reading up a bit more on Python and then coming back to this question and seeing if you could answer it yourself.

Comment: Seems like a "gimme teh codez". Will flag.

Comment: Why are you guys giving me such a tough time on this site? I'm self taught. At least tell me what the "large issues" are.

Comment: @german it's become the accepted (and often encouraged) "culture" of this site, and users will often adamantly back up their comments by linking to Rules on http://stackoverflow.com/help, but blatantly disregard the [Help Center > Our model
Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) which states "Rudeness and belittling language are not okay." So unfortunately, we just have to accept it. In the meantime, I'll try to think of suggestions for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's really encouraging.

Comment: by the way, how do you "start" your script, there's two functions, but no function callers. when I run it, nothing happens.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I got it, no problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heres a link that can help you understand how to go about this the right way http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/game-hangman